# Sharepoint 2013: Where'd the Design Manager Customisation Go?

Tags: 2013, design, manager

We had a vendor set up our SharePoint 2013 site for us with custom branding and look and feel.  I've used the Design Manager (Site Settings->Change the Look and selecting a built-in composed look) to change the look and feel of a site, not realising it's the parent site of what I was trying to change, and gone to revert it to realise that the customisations don't show up in Design Manager.  Is this normal? When you import a design package is it able to be used elsewhere (saved in the design manager somewhere?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out.  While the customisations don't show up in the installed themes in Site Settings->Change the Look, they do add items to the master pages which are changed when you select a built-in composed look.  I was able to revert what I'd done by selecting new master pages in the master pages settings (we had Seattle, Oslo (both built in), and one named after our business which was obviously what the vendor delivered).  You can then force the look to cascade down which fixed all our issues.